# JSF Page navigation using rewrite (Need to change browser url for navigation )

Tags: jsf, redirect, navigation, jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

I have my RewriteConfiguration class

```
@RewriteConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfigurationProvider extends HttpConfigurationProvider {

    @Override
    public int priority() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * map URL with resource
     */
    public Configuration getConfiguration(ServletContext context) {
        return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()

    .addRule(Join.path("/page1/{param}").to("/view/page1.jsf?product={param}"))
                .addRule(Join.path("/page2/{param}").to("/view/page2.jsf?product={param}"))

        ;
    }
}
```

My managedBean

```
@Named("myBean")
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
public class PageManagedBean {
 ...
    public String success(){
        return "success";
    }

...
}
```

In my page1.xhtml my submit button code is

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.success()}" id="nextButton" value="NEXT" >
    <f:param name="product" value="#{param.product}"></f:param>
</h:commandButton>
```

And my navigation rule in faces-config.xml is

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/view/page1.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/view/page2.jsf</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/error-500</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

The problem is :
When I am click on submit button from `page1` , in the browser URL it is showing `/page1/xyz` even-though the page is redirected to `page2`

The requirement is to change the url to `/page2/xyz`.

I added `<redirect/>`  in `faces-config.xml` , but in URL it is showing the full path of the `page2` (`/view/page2.jsf`) .

How can I redirect to next page with change in URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Join looks strange. You should not use query parameters in the `to()` part. Rewrite automatically converts all path parameters to query parameters.

So instead of:

```
.addRule(Join.path("/page1/{param}").to("/view/page1.jsf?product={param}"))
```

You should try:

```
.addRule(Join.path("/page1/{product}").to("/view/page1.jsf"))
```

Now your navigation should work. But please include the redirect element. That’s required for the URL to change.